# SharePoint Site Language Translator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, multilingual

Hi is there any application or tools that we can automatically change the page content labels etc.. to other languages in SharePoint?

Right now we are developing our new site and we need to make our region site to be multilingual

eg:
China Site  ( user can choose English/ Chinese language )

Thanks.
Ryan

Comment: Do you means multilingual or you want all content on the pages do translated

Comment: Multi lingual ,where we'll just create only site then user has an option to switch language without changing/redirecting them to new site,

Comment: Hi in SharePoint for Multilingual there are target sites are created for as many labels you want languages and site will be redirect to different site but having same content as of source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are developing a new site, you can think about a multilingual site.

SharePoint Server and SharePoint Online have features that enable you to support users in different regions or users who speak different languages. You can use these features to create websites in different languages, or to enable users to view sites in their preferred language.
(Pay attention that this feature does not apply to SharePoint Foundation 2013)

To determine your multilingual requirements, you must do the following:

1. Determine the languages and locales that you must support.
2. Determine the language pack requirements for sites and users.
3. Decide whether you want to use the variations feature.

You can check below articles for more information about "Create multilingual sites in SharePoint ":

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-for-multilingual-sites

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-multi-language-website-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Also check this article:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-multilingual-features-53411469-53e3-4570-95e2-3651f166174f

Comment: Hi we need that only user has an option to switch language without changing/redirecting them to new site,